# Discount on products if selected from "Category A" but not from "Category B"

Tags: magento-1.9, category, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, catalog-price-rules

We have 8 products in "Category A" and same 8 products in "Category B". We want a functionality where when customer selects same product from CatB, they should get discount and not when they select from CatA. 

If we make a rule with "Category is 10", then that is always try because this works on product level.